# ObjectContext error when modifying a entity from database using Entity Framework in MVVM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm creating a WPF application. I have an Oracle database in which I have a table named `Register` and has relationships with  `Name` table. I have created the Models using Entity Framework and I have a WPF form binding with a View Model to create a new Name and assign it to a Register.

Now, when I create a new Name, I took a Register, and assign that Name to the Registry like this:

```
public class CreateRegisterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     private BLName blName = new BLName();
     private BLRegister blRegister = new BLRegister();
     private REGISTER register;

     public CreateRegisterViewModel() { }

     public CreateRegisterViewModel(REGISTER register)
     {
        this.register = register;
     }
     public void CreateName()
     {
        Name name = new Name();
        Name.FirstName = FirstName;
        Name.SecondName = SecondName;
        blName.CreateName(name);            
        register.NAMES.Add(name);                
        blRegister.ModifyRegister(register);
      }
    }
```

The Business Logic class where I call the ModifyRegister method look like this:

```
public class BLRegister : IDisposable
{
    private DARegister da = new DARegister();
    public void ModifyRegister(REGISTER register)
    {
            try
            {
                da.ModifyRegister(register);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
    }
}
```

And in business logic I'm calling ModifyRegister from a Data Access class like this:

```
public class DARegister: IDARegister {
 private Entities context = new Entities();
 public void ModifyRegister(REGISTER register) {
  var entity = context.REGISTER.Where(i => i.ID_REGISTER == register.ID_REGISTER).FirstOrDefault();
  if (entity != null) {
   entity.CREATION_DATE = register.CREATION_DATE;
   entity.MODIFY_DATE = register.MODITY_DATE;
   entity.NAMES = register.NAMES;
   entity.SERIAL = register.SERIAL
   context.SaveChanges();
  }

 }
}
```

And this is extending the methods from an interface like this:

```
interface IDARegister : IDisposable
    {
        void ModifyRegister(REGISTER register);
    }
```

Now, my problems are when I run the CreateName method from the ViewModel, it throws me the next error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   SIGEPE.BussinesLogic.dll but was not handled in user code The
>   relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because of they
>   are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

I don't know what it means by referring two ObjectContext, I'm new in C# and Entity Framework and I don't know where is my error. How can I solve this? Can it be a problem with the database or is a problem of the entity framework?

Comment: Can you place a few breakpoints and pin point the exact line of code that is throwing the exception?

Comment: Seems to me like you are assigning navigation properties like "NAMES" from an object that was not created or retrieved using the same object context "Entities" instance that you are using the save them "calling SaveChanges()"

Comment: @Darkonekt the line that is throwing this is the SaveChanges() lines, before that the Bussines Logic file catch the exception

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is that you are trying to assign "entity.NAMES = register.NAMES".... The problem is that the entities in register.NAMES are NOT part of the Entities object context inside the DARegister class.  This means that the objects inside the register.NAMES cannot be associated to entity.NAMES.

Comment: @Darkonekt and what can I do to assign it the same context, o to reduce it to have only one context?

Comment: @Darkonekt how can I add a Name object to Register.NAMES that be of the same context?

Comment: you most likely have to create new objects and "map the properties" of the incoming objects.  After created or updating the main object then you can "foreach on NAMES" and add them one by one and save them